# iOS – Showing a view controller already in the navigation stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This is probably easily sorted but I can't figure it out. I have a tab bar application with two tabs, each tab has a `UINavigationController`.

Let's say that I in tab 1 push a viewcontroller called `ItemViewController`, then I go to tab 2. From tab 2 I want to programatically display the `ItemViewController`. So it should first take me to tab 1 and then display the `ItemViewController`.

This is easily achievable by just tapping on the tab 1 tab item but I want to do this programtically for other reasons.

What I'm doing right now to achieve this:

```
[tab1NavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
[tab1NavController pushViewController:itemViewController animated:NO];
```

I would like to be able to do something like this in pseudo-code:

```
if(viewControllerIWantToDisplayIsOnNavStack)
[tab1NavController presentViewController:viewControllerIWantToDisplay];
else
//instantiate and pushviewcontroller onto stack
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// check if the desired controller is on the stack in tab 1
if([[tab1NavController viewControllers] containsObject:viewControllerIWantToDisplay]) {
    // desired controller is on the stack, let's see if it's on top
    if(tab1NavController.topViewController == viewControllerIWantToDisplay) {
        // no need to do anything
        }
    else {
        // we need to pop to the desired view controller
        [tab1NavController popToViewController:viewControllerIWantToDisplay animated:NO];
    }
} else {
    // desired controller not on the stack
    [tab1NavController pushViewController:viewControllerIWantToDisplay animated:NO];
}
```

So you don't have to pop to root view controller in the tab 1 any more.

Comment: From where do I get a reference to `viewControllerIWantToDisplay` ?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to it somewhere, I suggest appDelegate class, it is easily accessible throughout the application. Or, if you are sure that there will be only one `viewControllerIWantToDisplay` on the `tab1NavController`, then the better approach may be to check the kind of the class, like BobDev suggests. But in this case, you will have to check the entire array of `viewControllers` to find your controller.

Answer (score 1):

for me following way worked, i used loop to check if class is in stack array

```
 NSInteger viewControllersCount = 0;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = nil;
    Yourcontroller *viewController = nil;

    NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    viewControllersCount = viewControllers.count - 1;

    for (int i = viewControllersCount ; i > 0 ; i--) {
        rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[Yourcontroller class]])
        {
            viewController = (NWAAccountViewC *)rootViewController;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy to programmatically select another tab, just do this:

```
tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = tabNr;
```

But I see you already know this. You can check whether the top view controller on the stack is the type of viewcontroller you need by checking like this:

```
if([navigationcontroller.topviewcontroller isKindOfClass:[Yourcontroller class]])
{
    //change tabbar or something else
}
```